# Integer solutions to $xyz = w^2(x+y+z)$

Tags: algorithms, diophantine-equations, integer-programming

I'm looking for a way to enumerate all positive integer solutions of the equation

$xyz = w^2(x+y+z)$

where $w \le W$ and $1 \le x \le y \le z$.

Could anyone provide a hint at how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the following method for computing the answer: first, multiply both sides by $x$ and factor the equation as

$$(xz - w^2)(xy - w^2) = w^2(x^2 + w^2)$$

Then iterating through all $x$ and $w$ I factorize the right-hand side, find all its divisors $f$ and leave only those that yield integer values

$$z = (w^2 + f)/x, \qquad y = w^2(x^2+w^2 + f)/(xf)$$

Answer (score 1):

Generalizing individ's answer,
in
$xyz=w^2(x+y+z)
$,
if
$x+y = z$,
then
$xy(x+y)=2w^2(x+y)
$
or
$xy = 2w^2$.

If
$r(x+y) = z$
where $r$ is rational,
then
$xyr(x+y)=(1+r)w^2(x+y)
$
or
$rxy = (1+r)w^2$
or
$xy = (1+\frac1{r})w^2
$.

Therefore,
for each $w^2$,
for any $r$
such that
$w^2/r$
is an integer,
look at all the factorizations of
$w^2(1+1/r)=xy$.

In particular,
if $r = \frac1{n}$
for integer $n$,
let $xy$ go over the
factors of
$(n+1)w^2$,
choose those where
$n$ divides $x+y$,
and let
$z = (x+y)/n$.

To verify,
$xyz
=(n+1)w^2(1/n)(x+y)
=(n+1)w^2(x+y)/n
$
and
$w^2(x+y+z)
=w^2(x+y+(x+y)/n)
=w^2(x+y)(n+1)/n
$.

If $r=1$,
this gives the first solution.

If $r=2$,
we look at the
factors of $xy=3w^2$
with the same parity
(this implies that
$w$ is even),
and let
$z = (x+y)/2$.

For general $n$,
we want
$n | x+(n+1)w^2/x$.

It's getting late
and I'm tired,
so I'll stop here.

Comment: Marty, thank you for your help. So if I understand this correctly, we replace $z$ with a rational $r=m/n$, where $m|w^2$ and $n|x+y$. So for a given $w=1...N$ we can find all factors of $w^2$ and let $m$ range over those. As for $n$, the condition $z\ge y$ roughly translates into $n\le 2m$, which means $n$ can go up to $2w^2$. Thus the overall complexity is approximately $O(N^3\log N)$, which is a little too high. Is there a way to prune search space for $n$?

Answer (score 0):

$$xyz=w^2(x+y+z)$$
Decompose into factors of the number.
$$tp=2w^2$$
Then the decision on the record.
$$x=t$$

$$y=p$$

$$z=t+p$$